# The difference between 'singlestep' and 'singlestep_enabled' variables in QEMU

Tags: gdb, qemu, processor, emulation

So, im integrating a new particular arch into the QEMU emulator (implementation in QEMU is like OpenRISC arch, so you can rely on this one when answering), and im running some tests.
QEMU is of version 2.0.93

1. When im running the test in normal mode, QEMU finishes with wrong answer
2. When im running in `-singlestep` mode, QEMU fails with my assertion from getting more than 1 command into the TargetBlock when running singlestep
3. When im running QEMU with GDB, which providing `singlestep_enabled` mode, var equals 7 (meaning `SSTEP_ENABLE|SSTEP_NOIRQ|SSTEP_NOTIMER`), im getting the right answer for the test.

The question is, why is this so, and what is the actual execution difference betweeen 2 those modes?
I didn't find much in the web as its less then nothing of documentation for QEMU so far

Comment: @Peter Teoh once said that singlestep_enabled enables the 'hardware singlestep emulation' (stackoverflow.com/a/23847965/2238032), but if someone tells me why user is not allowed to use this mode, and gdb is, i would appreciate that

Comment: **USEFUL!**
In addition, I have to say that GDB basically flushes ( `tb_flush()` func ) every TB so it puts every bunch of code _to the same TB every time_.

Plus, if qemu finds a code that equals to some code in some previously generated Tb, it loads it from its Page Table (Page Descs, to be exact) instead of re-generating it to new TB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two flags perform different functions.

'singlestep' is a bool that indicates whether the command line '-singlestep' option was given. This basically puts QEMU into a mode where it puts only one guest instruction in each TB. We don't actually stop after each instruction.

'singlestep_enabled' is per-CPU, and is set (via the cpu_single_step() function) when the gdb stub wants to perform a singlestep. The target- frontend will then emit code that executes a single instruction and raises a debug exception. (The gdb stub will then handle that exception and return control to the debugger.)

The third kind of singlestep you may see in the code is emulation of the target CPU's built in debug singlestep behaviour, which we implement on at least x86 and ARM. This is generally handled in a target-specific way to provide whatever the guest CPU's required stepping semantics are.

If your code is generating different answers for single-step and normal operation, this probably means you have a bug in how you're generating TCG code: possibly not having the right flags on a helper function, or mishandling TCG locals. Or you might not be correctly restoring state when a load/store exception occurs.

Side note: 2.0.93 is an old version of QEMU, and not even a release version (it's a release-candidate for 2.1). If you're developing a new target front end you should be working with current git master.

Comment: Thank you very much for covering answer.
But actually, what my arch is doing wrong is only putting more than 1 command to the TB in `-singlestep` mode, and raising the assert therefore.
I assume my translation function not working correctly then.
Mark me if I said smth. wrong

Comment: and tell me more about that 'third kind of singslestep'. I've just checked ARM arch's translation source, and I didn't find any major differences with a common singslestep. Where is it located?

Comment: The ARM architectural singlestep is what is handled via the pstate_ss and ss_active flags. There's a big comment about how these work in translate.c. (This is all newer than 2.0.93; as I said, you should be using up to date QEMU if you're writing new features for it.)